# How can I include a servlet in a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, servlets, include

is it possible to include a servlet in a jsp page? if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include it (via one of the JSP directives), but you can chain to it.  There's a great example over at JGuru.  See [this article](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=740).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [Jakarta IO Tag Library](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/io-doc/intro.html) to include the contents of one URL (it can be any URL) inside a JSP page.